# Guide for switching from RedHat/CentOS/Fedora to Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, centos, fedora, redhat

I recently switched from CentOS to Ubuntu, mainly to get newer packages but keep system stability.

Can anyone point to a list (or submit one) of changes between these platforms, like instead of `x` you'll use `y`, this is located here, ...

Examples

```
# commands
yum -> apt-get
chkconfig -> susv-rc-conf
service httpd restart -> apache2ctl restart

# users (ownership)
httpd -> www-data

# locations
/etc/httpd -> /etc/apache2
```

Comment: actually, retarting apache should be done by /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this links could help you :)

[Switching To Ubuntu From Linux RedHat Enterprise Linux And Fedora](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/%20RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora)

[Differences Between Red Hat-style and Debian-style Distributions](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/Differences_Between_Red_Hat-style_and_Debian-style_Distributions)